# Richfaces 4.1 with JSF 2.1.7: resources are all in the body instead of head of the html document

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jboss7.x, mojarra

I was wondering if anyone has experienced a similar problem.

I just tried upgrading to JBoss AS 7.1.1 which comes prepackaged with JSF 2.1.7. Before I was using JSF 2.0.4 and everything was fine with RichFaces (btw I am using 4.1.0.Final in both scenarios). Now with Mojarra 2.1.7, it seems that all my Richfaces resources such as javax.faces.resource/richfaces.js.seam and javax.faces.resource/richfaces-event.js.seam are being included in the body of the rendered html page instead of the head. I am getting a lot of Richfaces is not defined errors because I am trying to use js richfaces methods elsewhere in my code. It just won't work since all the richfaces js files are loaded in the body.

I have tried researching this issue online and I can't find any info on it. I have an h:head tag in my document so that isn't the issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty serious problem. Have you reported it to the RichFaces guys?

Comment: Thanks for responding BalusC. Yes I've reported it on the RichFaces forum but no one has responded. I'm wondering if I need to add some configuration steps for this to work. I know that jsf-impl is responsible for resource loading and I've tried really hard to find answers online but no such luck.

Comment: I commented on the forum thread: https://community.jboss.org/thread/198285

Comment: In JSF 2, there is a different mechanism for including script resources in the head or body sections.  The &lt;h:outputScript> tag has a <code>target</code> attribute which tells JSF where to put the script include.  I looked at your sample code, and I didn't see anything obviously wrong.  But it's a start.  Good luck!